# Why is_same compilation failed when use enable_if, but is_same_v pass

Tags: c++, g++

### environment

x86-64 gcc 12.2, where you can try at https://godbolt.org/z/eTvTf7n3n and https://godbolt.org/z/4W7hM3Pzs

### code

```
#include <type_traits>

// pass
template<std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same_v<int, int>, bool> = 0>
void f1(){
}

// Compilation failed
template<std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<int, int>::value, bool> = 0>
void f2(){
}


int main()
{
}
```

### question

Why function `f1` and `f2` behaves differently? `is_same_v` is just a constant time wrapper of `is_same::value`, I don't understand what makes the difference.

Comment: Both should fail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code is ill-formed NDR<sup>1</sup>. Both overloads are rejected by Clang and MSVC.

**[`[temp.res.general]/6.1`](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp#res.general-6.1)**

> The validity of a template may be checked prior to any instantiation. ... The program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required, if:
>
> — no valid specialization can be generated for a template ... and the template is not instantiated, ...

---

<sup>1</sup> NDR = "no diagnostic required", meaning the program is invalid, but the compilers are not required to catch that (not required to emit an error/warning message, aka "a diagnostic").